# PhpStorm with Live Edit on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, phpstorm, liveedit

Can I use Live Edit plugin on Mozilla Firefox and if I can how to do that?

Comment: Live edit only works in Chrome; for Firefox support, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1805

Answer (score 1):

You cannot -- **LiveEdit plugin works with Chrome browser only**.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html?search=live%20e

---

If it has to be Firefox .. then you should try some another solution, **LiveReload** perhaps.